# One route for two different urls in expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, routes

Can I separate two different urls in one route like this?

```
app.get('/:category/events', (req, res) => {

let category = req.params.category;

if (category == 'bike') {
//connecting to database
    res.render('events', {
        title: 'bike events'
    })
} else if (category == 'car') {
//connecting to database
    res.render('events', {
        title: 'car events'
    })
} else {
    res.status(404).redirect('/error')
}});
```

Or theres much better way to do that? I bet it is.

Comment: Why you can't create two routes: `/bike/events` and `/car/events` and avoid using if statement?

Comment: Actually I can but I'm curious. It can't be done like this?

Comment: If your action is so simple, you could use solution suggested by @Paolo Mangia, but if you want to extend the functionality, you will need to create own function for each if-else blocks, but in that case creation two separate actions is a preferable solution.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Ill do that.

Answer (score 0):

maybe:

```
res.render('events', {
  title: category + ' events'
});
```

Comment: title was just an example. What if I need to take some data from database?

Comment: If you have the same logic for each category my example will do (database interactions included) otherwise you would have to make 2 different routes.